# Ajax call to web URL results in javascript error

Tags: javascript, ajax

We have been using Ajax calls for our applications and it has been working well for the urls within the server domain. But, when i use ajax call for url on web, i find it failing without proper error message. I searched on web with the given details, but couldn't find any reasonable cause or solution to this issue.

My code is a simple ajax call as below.

```
var url = "http://www.google.com";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    alert('done');
    }
  };
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

If the url is from the server domain, this works without any issue, but when this is a open internet url like google, it fails with different behaviors in different browsers.

In IE9, xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true) gives an 'Javascript error:Access denied' and xmlhttp.status becomes ' could not complete the operation due to error c00c023f'

In Chrome and FF, no error is shown in the log, but xmlhttp.status becomes 0

In all cases, the ajax call is NOT successful.

What might be the cause of such problem? I don't think this is a network issue as i can access the google url if tried directly on the browser. So, what might block it from trying a ajax call from browser?

Regards
Vijay.K

Answer (score 1):

Cross Domain Queries do not work in IE 9, Chrome, Firefox. It is a security issue. But, why do you still use XHR? You can use jQuery's awesome [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) right? For this you can simply use this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.google.com/",
        success: function(){
           alert("Done!");
        }
    });
});
```

The problem here is that you are trying to access a cross domain, which is a security violation and the state will always return `0` irrespective of whatever you do. Check the fiddle.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uazqY/